# Python Tkinter Spinbox dependencies

Tags: python, user-interface, dynamic, tkinter, dependencies

I have tried looking for awhile but have come up empty, so forgive me if this has been asked before. Hopefully I can explain well enough what I'm trying to achieve.

I am trying to create a simple GUI for asset management for my studio and am having a bit of a trouble with Tkinter's Spinbox, specifically having dependencies with it. We have a specific file structure (which for test purposes is about 4 folders deep) for various assets to be organized into. I'm a little new to Tkinter as a whole but have created the GUI well enough I believe right now for testing purposes (please guide me in correcting any mistakes that you may see.)

As it stands, on open I have my two Spinboxes as well as my button. The first Spinbox performs as expected but I'm having trouble when I'm trying to make the 2nd Spinbox show the values from the selection in the first Spinbox. The second Spinbox only wants to show me the first folder in the hierarchy instead of showing all of the folders (not their subsequent subfolders, too) in that directory. How can I get the second Spinbox to show me the other folders as well and update as the first Spinbox changes? I essentially need it to dynamically populate and re-populate as the option in the first spinbox changes. I've pasted my code below. Any help would be immensely appreciated. :)

```
import os
import Tkinter as tk

mainpath = "C:\\"

def mywindow():
    top = tk.Tk()
    top.wm_title("Muse Asset Manager v01.00")
    top.geometry("+825+500")
    frame = tk.Frame(top)

    spin01 = tk.Spinbox(frame, values = ([i for i in os.listdir(mainpath)]), wrap = True, state = "readonly")

    def secondspincommand():
        newspin01 = spin01.get()
        myspin = [i for i in os.listdir(mainpath + str(newspin01))]
        print myspin
        spin02.config(values = myspin)
    spin02 = tk.Spinbox(frame, values = "", wrap = True, state = 'readonly', command = secondspincommand)

    b1 = tk.Button(frame, text = "Import")
    def button01():
        print secondpath
        top.destroy()
        return
    b1.configure(command = button01)

    spin01.grid(row=1)
    spin02.grid(row=2)
    b1.grid(row=3)
    frame.pack()
    frame.mainloop()
mywindow()
```

Edited for clarity and to turn code into a minimal, complete, verifiable example

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run without having to have your Y: drive attached to our system?

Comment: Also, what exactly is wrong here? It seems very odd that you've put the code to populate the second spinbox into the second spinbox's command instead of the first's. Is that the problem?

Comment: Or maybe "the first folder in the hierarchy instead of all of them" means that you wanted to populate it with all files recursively under the directory selected in the first spinbox, rather than only those directly in that directory?

Comment: Hello abarnert. I'm working on reducing it to a minimal, complete, and verifiable code. My apologies. The later, I need the second spinbox to be populated with all the files recursively under the selected directory in the first spinbox, and update as the first spinbox changes. Right now, I just get the first folder in the selected directory of the first spinbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you have two separate problems here.

---

> I need the second spinbox to be populated with all the files recursively under the selected directory in the first spinbox …

You're calling [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). That just lists the files directly under a given directory, the same as the `dir` command at the Windows command line.

If you want to get all the files *recursively* underneath it, you need a function that lists all such files recursively. That's what [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) is for.

Of course `walk` isn't quite as simple as `listdir`, but that's because it's a lot more flexible. If what you want is just the regular files (not the subdirectories on the way), and the complete path to each one, this should do it:*

```
myspin = [os.path.join(root, file)
          for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mainpath + newspin01)
          for file in files]
```

<sub>* Notice that I got rid of the extra `[i for i in …]` around the outside of the whole thing, and the `str(…)` around `newspin01`, because there's no reason to write a list comprehension that gathers all of the elements of a list into a copy of the same list, or to call `str` on a string.</sub>

---

> … and update as the first spinbox changes.

Then you need to trigger that to happen on the *first* listbox's change, not the *second's*.

So, do this:*

```
def firstspincommand():
    # the code you used to have as secondspincommand

spin01 = tk.Spinbox(frame, values=([i for i in os.listdir(mainpath)]), 
                    wrap=True, state="readonly", command=firstspincommand)
spin02 = tk.Spinbox(frame, values=[""], 
                    wrap=True, state='readonly')
```

<sub>* I also changed a few things to be PEP8-compliant, and readable on a reasonable-sized screen, and I used `values=[""]` instead of `values=""` because, while the latter is technically an iterable of strings, it's a bit confusing to use it that way.</sub>

Of course you may want some *other* code to run on a change to the second box's selection, but clearly not the code that populates the second box.

Comment: Hi abarnert. I appreciate your help. I think I might have misunderstood a bit. I'm not wanting a full recursive walk. os.listdir is giving me what I'm looking for as I'm not needing to go through all the subfolders in each subfolder. I just need the first sets. As for the second issue, the code listed is still only giving me the first folder. I think I may have messed up my wording a bit. I need the second spinbox to dynamically be populated (re-populated?) based off of the information in the first spinbox.

Comment: @Sbenjamin: The code listed does exactly what you're asking for. See [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eSDCjm6b) to see how I tested it.

Comment: You're right, the code does do what I was looking for. I compared what I was doing to your pastebin and then to our discussions and I'm not sure why but I was misunderstanding what you were saying even though it was fairly clear (long day when I was reading it I suppose?) However, I do apologize and greatly appreciate your time and help. I ended up switching over to PyQt mainly for easier aesthetic purposes and have gotten it all to work fine, but this will definitely help for the other projects I have on my horizon. I have made sure to accept your answer. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @Sbenjamin: Probably a good call. In my experience, PyQt requires a bit more effort up-front (harder to install, more of a learning curve, each GUI has to be designed at least a bit before you slap it into your code) than Tkinter, but for many "advanced" things it's a whole lot simpler and more consistent…